# Upstart reports "Job is already running" but process doesn't exist, and no PID file

Tags: upstart, init.d, minidlna

So, I have MiniDLNA installed, and recently have found that I cannot start it using Upstart.

Running `sudo start minidlna` returns:

```
minidlna start/running, process [num]
```

But no process is started (there should also be an additional status report line for the startup of MiniDLNA).

I get the same with `sudo service minidlna start`

Upstart logs (/var/log/upstart/minidlna.log) show:

```
start: Job is already running: minidlna
```

Attempting to stop or restart using upstart returns:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
```

I can successfully start MiniDLNA in any of the following ways:

- `/usr/bin/minidlnad -f /etc/minidlna.conf`
- `/etc/init.d/minidlna start`
- `start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /run/minidlna.pid --chuid minidlna:minidlna --exec /usr/bin/minidlnad -- -f /etc/minidlna.conf -P /run/minidlna.pid`

I've also tried deleting the MiniDLNA user/group and re-adding with no success.

This state survives after reboot.

I'm at my wit's end. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your problem is at http://efiop-notes.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-set-pid-using-nslastpid.html, which is a much starter way of taking care of upstart issues than by cycling through all pids until you create the one that upstart is looking for.

Simply compile the program with the C compiler and run it as sudo with the PID that upstart knows about, and Voila!

HTH,
Shailen

Comment: While the link may contain the answer you should include details of the solution in your answer as well in case the link goes down.